# Ext.net dynamic gridPanel reading from an httpHandler

Tags: asp.net, ext.net, gridpanel

I am adding a dynamic grid to a view port on click of a button the data in the store is from an ajax proxy , I am using the same  code as in http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/Saving_Variations/HttpHandler/ 
but the difference is I am adding it in behind code .

First problem is all the icon are not showing it is saying that it is cannot be found. 
Second problem is that I am getting the headers and the buttons and they are functioning properly but there is no data displayed in the grid ...

Please help I have tried every thing I know here .

Comment: have you checked the icon path? also, are you sure you use the correct ext.net version? and last but not least, have you called `store.DataBind();` on a valid DataSource that you have modelled appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the icons may need to be registered in order for them to be rendered. Use the following code. This is especially true when loading icons dynamically.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!X.IsAjaxRequest)
     {     
          this.resourceManager.RegisterIcon(Icon.Lorry);

    }
}
```

Secondly, if you are seeing blank rows in the grid it would suggest the data is being loaded but that you have a case mis-match between your ModelField and Column DataIndex value(s). DataIndex values are CASE SENSITIVE.

I hope this helps.

Thanks,

Gav